# How to automatically start own executable after windows restart?

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, registry, winreg

Let's assume that I have a C# .NET 2.0+ application running on windows. And at some certain point in time it forces Windows to restart. How can I automatically start this application again after windows restarts to continue program to do some work?? I need to do it in code somehow, but I don't know how. Point me, please to some info on this or some pieces of code will be great. Thanks!

Comment: Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483230/how-can-i-run-an-app-automatic-after-restart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options.

1 Register it as a windows service.

2 Put a link in startup section of Start Button

3 Create an entry in registry `(HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run)`

The best one is the first one, as this is the recommended method to automatically start applications. You will benefit from:

- Standard control in **services.msc**
- Applications that allow you to monitor windows services status
- Msbuild or powershell commands that allow you to easily interact with your service in order to deploy as part of your continuous integration process.

But your application will require some changes and has to be a console app.. Check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/aa984464%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to make yourself an idea. If you have a winforms app go for options 2 or 3 (3 is better)

Comment: Number 1 would not work for applications with `GUI` easily (there are tools to do that) and the best is number 3 (standard method) because it is not as easy as number 2 to be removed accidentally. There are other ways as `run-once`... Also he should decide to run it for all users or specific ones which is supported by number 2 and 3.